# scrollViewDidScroll is not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom tab bar with a horizontal scroll view underneath that. 
Tab bar contains 5 buttons each of them calls one of the five custom keyboards (they are placed on a scroll view). You can switch between these keyboards scrolling the scroll view or pressing the buttons.

Question: how do I change the states of the buttons (default <-> selected) when I switch between keyboards using scroll view?

*Visual:*

[image]

Comment: Please actually enter the image description - and provide some more information (including code) so people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded your project and you have some issues there. You're implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` but for some reason, the method you have in your app is wrong for the `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)`.

The method needs to be declared like in this way:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {}
```

You cannot change anything in that method and in your case you changed the name of the argument as the name of your `UIScrollView`, just a minor change but it implies that you will not be notified every time the `UIScrollView` did scroll.

So let's go back to your problem. To achieve what do you want you to need to calculate the current page where you are inside the `UIScrollView` or in your case the number of the button, we can calculate that using the following formula:

```
let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
let page = Int(round((scrollView.contentOffset.x ) / (pageWidth)))
```

Afterwards what you need is update your selected button when the scroll finish of scrolling. The problem with the `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` method is that this method is called several times during the scrolling process, so we need a method that is called only when the scrolling is finished, and it's the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_:)`.

So you need to add the following code in your code:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(round((scrollView.contentOffset.x ) / (pageWidth)))

    let previousIndex = selectedIndex
    tabBarButtons[previousIndex].isSelected = false

    selectedIndex = page
    tabBarButtons[page].isSelected = true
}
```

I tested the behaviour in your app and works fine. If you have any trouble I have your project modified, but the only thing you need is to add the above method in your `UIViewController` and it should work fine

I hope this help you

Comment: @Rdk I just copied you code and put it there you can change it with the name you want. The answer is no, the variable is only visible inside the function.  If the answer solve your question please accept it to it can be help anyone else

Comment: Thanks! Another question - you create and use "pageWidth" instead of just scrollView.frame.size.width just for clarity, right?

Comment: I created the constant to avoid refer every time the long name of the width of the scrollView, you can use it you don't want to declare a new constant for it

Comment: Makes sense. I'm just trying to understand. All these things are pretty new for me, so I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

UIScroll has a delegate method called scrollViewDidScroll. This gets called every time the user scrolls. The scrollView has a property called contentOffset. That property tells you exactly how much as been scrolled. Use this method and property to branch your logic.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that. Looks like I did something wrong. I have an array with all 5 tab bar buttons - `@IBOutlet var tabBarButtons: [UIButton]!` Then I use scrollViewDidScroll function but by some reasons it does not work `func scrollViewDidScroll(keyboardScrollView: UIScrollView) { if keyboardScrollView.contentOffset == CGPoint(x: 0, y: keyboardScrollView.contentOffset.y) { tabBarButtons[0].isSelected = true } }`  Repo: github.com/Rudko/boo